# How to assign a javascript variable to input text field?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've a variable called "numbers" in javascript and this variables holds 10 numbers from 0 to 9 as shown below.

```
var numbers = "0123456789";
```

Now what I want to be able to do is assigning each of these numbers to an input text field using document.getElementByID("a") = "";, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="a" value="" />
<input type="text" id="b" value="" />
<input type="text" id="c" value="" />
<input type="text" id="d" value="" />
<input type="text" id="e" value="" />
<input type="text" id="f" value="" />
<input type="text" id="g" value="" />
<input type="text" id="h" value="" />
<input type="text" id="i" value="" />
<input type="text" id="j" value="" />
```

Currently the following text fields above holding no values, but I want to be able to assign each of the numbers in variable "numbers" to each of the text fields above, so it would looks like this when user clicks on a button called click me.

```
<input type="text" id="a" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="b" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="c" value="2" />
<input type="text" id="d" value="3" />
<input type="text" id="e" value="4" />
<input type="text" id="f" value="5" />
<input type="text" id="g" value="6" />
<input type="text" id="h" value="7" />
<input type="text" id="i" value="8" />
<input type="text" id="j" value="9" />
```

Also is there any way to leave a text field empty if a particular number is = 0

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can get one number of the String using `numbers[2]` (to get the third character which is two), so something like `if(numbers[2] != 0) document.getElementById('c').value = numbers[2]` you might want to play with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var numbers = "0123456789";
var ids = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"];

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
{
    var el = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
    var num = numbers[i];

    if (num == "0")
        el.value = "";
    else
        el.value = num;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/LrJ5S/.

Comment: This code depends on numbers and ids having the same length. You should get the number with numbers[i % ids.length]

Comment: @esrange: I see no indication in OP's post that there will be more elements than numbers... why overcomplicate the solution with assumed requirements?

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I require, but will also check out other solutions! Thank you so muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuch!

Comment: Hi when I go to the link you've given it works but when I save it on my PC the input fields don't work... any idea why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: @Farzad: It looks like it was setting it up dependent on library MooTools.  Try this version, http://fiddle.jshell.net/LrJ5S/3/show/, do view-source, and copy that source to your local PC.  It should work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to mellamokb, another way of accomplishing the same:

```
var numbers = "abc0123abc0123";
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var i = 0;
for(var s = 0; s < inputs.length; s++) {
    inputs[s].value = numbers.charAt(i)!=0?numbers.charAt(i):'';
    i++;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGaBP/)

Comment: Thank you guys for all of your useful answers! WOW! :))

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help! Really appreciate your help! Can you please explain me the "for() {} statement"... especially this line of code "inputs[s].value = numbers.charAt(i)!=0?numbers.charAt(i):'';
    i++;" within the "for statement"... THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

Basic example with no checks on data size of inputs and string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myInputs">
      <input type="text" id="a" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="b" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="c" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="d" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="e" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="f" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="g" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="h" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="i" value="" />
      <input type="text" id="j" value="" />      
    </div>
    <button id="run">Run</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function putNumbers(){
           var numbers = "0123456789";
           var inputs = document.getElementById("myInputs").getElementsByTagName("input");
           for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
             var val = numbers.charAt(i);
             inputs[i].value = val==="0"?"":val;
           }  

        }

        document.getElementById("run").onclick = putNumbers;
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

[working Example](http://jsbin.com/edoxu4/2/edit)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help! Really appreciate your help! :) Can you please explain me the "for() {} statement"... PLEASE, I'm interested to learn rather than copy and paste! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Especially this line of code within the "for() {} statement" -> "inputs[i].value = val==="0"?"":val;"... Thanks :)

Comment: Docs for [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator) | [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) | [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)